# Why is there a thick line on the left side of each HTML calendar?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, outline

Here is a calendar that is laid out using flex:

https://jsfiddle.net/elmonty/mafhksjp/8/

Notice how each month has a thicker line on the left side below the heading rows. How can I get rid of this line?

Here is the complete HTML & CSS code:

```css
#calendars-container {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 9pt;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
}

table.calendar {
  outline: 1px solid #555;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
}

table.calendar thead {
  background-color: #e6eaef;
}

table.calendar th {
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

table.calendar th.month {
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  line-height: 1.75;
}

table.calendar td {
  padding: 2px 4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="calendars-container">

    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">June&nbsp;2023</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">July&nbsp;2023</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">August&nbsp;2023</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">September&nbsp;2023</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">October&nbsp;2023</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">November&nbsp;2023</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">December&nbsp;2023</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>31</td>
          <td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">January&nbsp;2024</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">February&nbsp;2024</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">March&nbsp;2024</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>31</td>
          <td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">April&nbsp;2024</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">May&nbsp;2024</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's caused by overlapping outlines among `table.calendar` elements. Have you considered adding a bit of space? https://jsfiddle.net/vy40hbsx/1/

Comment: Great suggestion from @MichaelBenjamin, but if you don`t want to add the spaces between the calendars consider this: https://jsfiddle.net/xt28eg7n/

The example is when you have two calendars next to each other, it needs a little bit of changes in the nth-childs...

Comment: @JakubŠtellner that is not ideal when there are 3 months side to side. elmonty if you need to have borders, go with michael's suggestion. OR you can choose to have only right and bottom thick borders, like shadow effect

Comment: I figured it out. I wondered why the thicker line doesn't appear in the heading rows and it's because those have a background color. Adding a background color to the <td> elements does the trick. https://jsfiddle.net/elmonty/mafhksjp/12/

Comment: Solution #2: Add a 1 pixel right and bottom margin to each calendar table to account for the outline.  `table.calendar {margin: 0 1px 1px 0;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt is right about the cause but not the solution. The solution is to add a 1px margin on the right and bottom of each calendar table.

`table.calendar {margin: 0 1px 1px 0;}`

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you can replace the `outline` with a `border`, and set a negative `margin` to `.calendar`:

```css
#calendars-container {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 9pt;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  margin:1px 0 0 1px; /* To compensate for the margin .calendar */
}

table.calendar {
  border: 1px solid #555; /*  */
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px; /*  */
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.calendar thead {
  background-color: #e6eaef;
}

table.calendar th {
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

table.calendar th.month {
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  line-height: 1.75;
}

table.calendar td {
  padding: 2px 4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="calendars-container">

    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">June&nbsp;2023</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">July&nbsp;2023</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">August&nbsp;2023</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">September&nbsp;2023</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">October&nbsp;2023</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">November&nbsp;2023</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">December&nbsp;2023</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>31</td>
          <td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">January&nbsp;2024</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">February&nbsp;2024</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">March&nbsp;2024</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>31</td>
          <td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">April&nbsp;2024</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">May&nbsp;2024</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You've got 1px borders butting up against each other. This is causing a 2px border. A little trick that'll work is to remove the `outline`, add a 1px `gap` on `#calendars-container` and use `box-shadow` to represent your borders. Because box-shadow is virtually drawn in and not a part of the box model they can overlap:

```
#calendars-container
{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 9pt;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    gap: 1px;
}

table.calendar
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #000;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hv8s5wd1/

```css
#calendars-container
{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 9pt;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  gap: 1px;
}

table.calendar
{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #000;
}

table.calendar thead {
  background-color: #e6eaef;
}

table.calendar th {
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

table.calendar th.month {
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  line-height: 1.75;
}

table.calendar td {
  padding: 2px 4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="calendars-container">

    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">June&nbsp;2023</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">July&nbsp;2023</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">August&nbsp;2023</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">September&nbsp;2023</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">October&nbsp;2023</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">November&nbsp;2023</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">December&nbsp;2023</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>31</td>
          <td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">January&nbsp;2024</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">February&nbsp;2024</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">March&nbsp;2024</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>31</td>
          <td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">April&nbsp;2024</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="month" colspan="7">May&nbsp;2024</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
          <th abbr="M">M</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="W">W</th>
          <th abbr="T">T</th>
          <th abbr="F">F</th>
          <th abbr="S">S</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```